# How to install package from a .tar.lz file

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin, tar, packages

I'm using bash (Cygwin, specifically). I'm trying to install [GNU dd_rescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html), which comes in a `.tar.lz` archive file.

When I use:

```
tar -xzf ddrescue-1.22.tar.lz
```

...it returns with the following error:

> gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
>   tar: Child returned status 1 tar:
>   Error is not recoverable: exiting now

When I use:

```
tar --lzip -xf ddrescue-1.22.tar.lz
```

...it returns with:

> tar (child): lzip: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
>   tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
>   tar: Child returned status 2
>   tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

How can I extract and install a package from an `lzip` archive file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> tar (child): lzip: Cannot exec: No such file or directory

`tar` complains that it can't find and execute `lzip`. I suggest to install `lzip` first.

Comment: Ah, so that's what that error meant. I just assumed lzip would be a part of the core utilities. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR ubuntu command:

`sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get -y install lzip`

[click to see source of command](https://installati.one/ubuntu/20.04/lzip/)
ready to use file explorer!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).